# No custom metrics being logged?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am logging custom metrics using `TrackMetric`:

```
var telemetry = new TelemetryClient();
telemetry.TrackMetric($"Cache Size", cache.Count());
```

But nothing appears in the portal:

[image: Custom metrics]

The output window when debugging shows the metrics being sent.  I'm not sure how else to debug this.

Comment: How long did you wait? It may take up to several minutes and also sometimes requires refreshing the entire page (F5) also, do you see other telemetry types reach the portal?

Comment: I waited at least 5 mins and I have developer mode enabled. Will check again when I'm back in the office.

Comment: They are showing now. I guess I just didn't wait long enough - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be several things that make new items show up later than you'd like:

1. latency in AI pipeline itself, which is *usually* just a couple minutes or less (you can always check http://aka.ms/aistatus to see if there's any non-normal latency going on)
2. if you added a *new* custom property or *new* custom metric, it might take time for that new field to show up as a field in the metadata that the charts/etc use to build themselves.  depending on timing here, especially if this is a brand new app, it can take up to ~15 minutes for a new property to show up in metadata if the stars are all unaligned... but normally much less than that.
3. once it is available in metadata, you might need to refresh in the portal if you've already opened Metrics Explorer for that AI resource for it to re-request metadata to see your field (normally just the "refresh" command on Metrics Explorer or an Overview blade is good enough to get that working, but doing a full refresh in the browser works as a last resort)

Comment: Thanks for this. A great resource for anyone else who might experience the same. Reason 2 seems like the most likely candidate for my case.